# Animate and simultaneously add class to li

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to animate a block of div and also at the same time add class to li, How can i do this?

My fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/AsfFQ/4/

When i click the div in 'red' background, it will animate 0px to left. How add a class "selected" to li's for every 20px of animation of the div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/AsfFQ/11/).

Here's the Javascript:

```
var timer, 
    selectLi = (function() {
        var $block = $('.block'),
            $container = $('.container'),
            $lis = $('.container ul li'),
            liWidth = $lis.width(),
            $selectedLi;

        return function() {
            var pos = $block.offset().left - $container.offset().left,
                liNum = Math.round(pos / liWidth);
            $selectedLi && $selectedLi.removeClass('selected');
            $selectedLi = $($lis.get(liNum));
            $selectedLi.addClass('selected');
        };
    })();

$('.block').click(function() {
    timer = setInterval(selectLi, 30);
    $(this).animate({
        left: 0
    }, function() {
        clearInterval(timer);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If using the new jQuery 1.8, you can actually perform an animation and get a promise back, the returned object also contains the animated state, tween etc, and you can use that to calculate what element to apply the class to, this is kinda experimental, and I just started playing around with this, but something like :

```
$(function() {
    $('.block').on('click', function(){
        var ani = $.Animation( this, {left:0}, {duration: 1000} );

        ani.progress(function(e) {
            var Now = e.tweens[0].now,
                idx = Math.round(Now/10);
            $(".container ul li").eq(idx).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
        });
    });    
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/AsfFQ/12/)
​

Comment: @user1184100 - actually it's pretty awesome! Not just my answer, but the fact that they added a deffered animation with tweening in 1.8 ?

Comment: you are right, but both the answers are awesome specially this one..but had to settle down for another ,thanks again for the code this is cool